# How to access V-for elements

Tags: vuejs2

I have Large Image elements dynamically rendered using v-for

```
<div class="preview-pic tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane" 
         v-bind:class="activeClass" 
         :id= index
         v-for="(imgLink, index) in itemSelected.itemImages" 
         v-bind:ref="index">
        <img :src="imgLink.urlLargeImage" />
     </div>
</div>
```

I also have Thumbnail images rendered in v-for

```
<li v-for="(imgLink, index) in itemSelected.itemImages">
    <a @click="onImgClicked" :data-target="'#' + index" data-toggle="tab">
        <img :src="imgLink.urlThumbnail" />
    </a>
</li>
```

in my methods:

```
methods:{
    onImgClicked: function (index) {
       document.getElementById(index).className="active"  // works but is it vue-way?
       this.$refs.0.className = "active" // only works if i know what index of the thumbnail will be clicked
    }
}
```

When a thumbnail image is clicked, I'd like to make it's corresponding large image to be active by setting the css class "active". I can accomplish this with document.getelementbyid, but is that the vue-way? My attempt with $refs

I also attempted using v-bind but I was unsuccessful because either all large images will be active or not active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want one image active at a time, add an `activeImage` property to your data.

```
data(){
    return {
        activeImage: null
    }
}
```

Modify your template in this way.

```
<div class="preview-pic tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane" 
         :class="{active: imgLink === activeImage}" 
         :id= index
         v-for="(imgLink, index) in itemSelected.itemImages" 
         v-bind:ref="index">
       <img :src="imgLink.urlLargeImage" />
     </div>
</div>

...

<li v-for="(imgLink, index) in itemSelected.itemImages">
  <a @click="activeImage = imgLink" 
     :data-target="'#' + index" data-toggle="tab">
    <img :src="imgLink.urlThumbnail" />
  </a>
</li>
```

And get rid of your `onImgClicked`. Also, you will want to set activeImage to null when you don't want *any* image active.

Alternatively, if more than one image could be active at a time, add a boolean active property to your imgLink objects, and change your template to

```
:class="{active: imgLink.active}"
```

and

```
@click="imgLink.active = !imgLink.active"
```